# Get decoded values in SQL Server that gets translated from other table

Tags: sql-server

I have a value in a table that's a foregin key. This returns a number which is a `code => InvoiceDevice.DeviceType`. That code is decoded in the `Code` table, at `Code.CodeValue`, then I can use `WHERE InvoiceDevice.DeviceType = Code.CodeValue`.

So for example:

1. InvoiceDevice.DeviceType = 2
2. Code.CodeValue at 2 = iPhone

This is no problem for one column. But how do I display the last value (iPhone) in a VIEW with 68 other columns? They need to be all translated from that code table! How would I do this for all of them?

Comment: Sounds like a design that ignored potential queries that would be required later. 68 encoded columns, all with *different* encoded values from a different table?

Comment: It is a terrible design that was done by a company we no longer work with, due to several instances like this one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps it would help if show some SQL where "this is no problem for one column", and how that doesn't apply to multiple columns.

Comment: As you said the design is awful....you are now stuck making 68 joins to this table. One for each lookup. UGH!!!

Comment: From what I hear, it sounds like a your "Code" table acts like a syscode (or system code) auxiliary table. Have you tried aliasing it and reusing the Code table multiple times in the same query? Something like SELECT ... FROM Invoice, Code AS CodeA, Code AS CodeB WHERE Invoice.DeviceType = CodeA.CodeValue AND Invoice.SalesType = codeB.CodeValue

Comment: Thats the problem, you cant do an AS something WHERE, several times because it complains. I think I might have to re do the whole table to make it fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use Pivot/Unpivot to make that.
I have try with 3 Fields, like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Field, Code.CodeValue
    FROM 
        (SELECT Id, Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM InvoiceDevice) AS sourc
        UNPIVOT (CodeId FOR Field IN (Field1, Field2, Field3)) AS unpvt
        INNER JOIN Code ON Code.Code = unpvt.CodeId
) AS unpivoted
PIVOT
(
    MIN(CodeValue)
    FOR Field IN (Field1, Field2, Field3)
) AS pvt;
```

But no idea about performance...

Answer (score 0):

Might be that this is a simple question of `JOIN`?

Not knowing your tables structure my magic crystal ball tells me you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
      ,c.* 
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN InvoiceDevice AS id ON t.code=id.DeviceType
INNER JOIN Code AS c ON c.CodeValue=id.CodeValue
```

The actual table and column names will need adaptions...

If the code entries within your tables are not unique for a given value, there might be additional columns you need to use as filters.

### UPDATE

Reading your question once again it sounds like there are just two tables involved. In this case something like this should help:

```
SELECT id.*
      ,c.* 
FROM InvoiceDevice AS id 
INNER JOIN Code AS c ON c.CodeValue=id.CodeValue
```

Comment: Yes, but this is for 68 fields, do I need 68 joins then?

Comment: @MarioLanda Well, what's wrong with 68 joins if the tables return codes? I do not know the design and the reason why it is done like this, but this might be perfectly okay... I've seen a table with 48 questions, living in 48 columns, each pointing to the same table for decoding. This is bad design and should be changed to a `1:n` related table. But if there are 68 meaningful columns - why not?